# What does random_state = 0 do when used as an argument to the SVC function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science, svm

I understand what `random_state = 0` does in train test split and other applications. However, I do not understand it in the context of Support Vector machines/support vector classifiers. I do not understand what is it setting exactly or how it helps to create a support vector classifier, and also what happens if I omit it. I see that it is used when creating the SVC shell before the SVC is trained, so I believe it does not refer to the training data. Please answer in simple terms as I am relatively new to SVM/SVC, thanks. The code context is as follows:

```py
from sklearn.svm import SVC 
OurSVM = SVC(kernel = 'poly', random_state = 0)
OurSVM.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Look at the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)

Comment: OP's looking for a simple explanation, and I think the documentation's language is pretty complex.

Comment: "I understand what random_state = 0 does in train test split and other applications. However, I do not understand it in the context of Support Vector machines/support vector classifiers." - but it does the exact same thing in this context as in the context you say you understand!

Comment: @ user2357112. I'm not sure how setting random_state = 0 comes in for creating a SVC ? I understand it for t5rain test split, however, what is it setting to 0 for a SVC ? In train test split, it is randomly starting at a different number in a certain list. Hoever for SVC, where is it randomly starting? What (where, how) list of numbers in that context?